# How can I give different id(or key?) for new compose function but same function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Comopsable
fun SomeScreen(
    data: MyData,
    layoutType: LayoutType
    onChangeLayoutField: () -> Unit
){
    Row{
        when(layoutType){
            is AType -> ALayout(data)
            is BType -> BLayout(data)
        }
        Button(
            onClick = onChangeLayoutField
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ALayout(
    choiceList: List<Choice>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(-1) }

    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(choiceList.size) { columnIndex ->
            val choice = choiceList[columnIndex]

            SingleSelectionButton(
                index = columnIndex,
                text = choice.label ?: "",
                isChecked = selectedIndex == columnIndex,
                fontSize = 13.sp,
                fontColor = Color.Gray002,
                onNotifyButtonState = { index, isChecked ->
                    selectedIndex = index
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

here's the sample code. I'd like to clear SomeLayout when the next layout after the button is clicked.

What I expected here is. When ALayout's data(from param) changes, the view clears when it recomposes. But, It isn't.

For example,

1. ALayout(dataA) -> ALayout(dataB) -> ALayout(dataC): SingleSelectionButton's isChecked state still remains.
   So, Let's say O is isChecked = true, and X is false.
   In ALayout, I made it X O X X, then click next button, then, X O X X state is still there, even last ALayout is still X O X X.
2. However, when there's other Layout which is BLayout here. It clears the previous ALayout state and works normal.
   For instance, ALayout(dataA) -> BLayout(dataB) -> ALayout(dataC).
   BLayout clears previous ALayout state so, new ALayout after BLayout shows X X X X which is correct.

I also tried with animation.

```
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = text, label = text)
    val caretIndex by transition.animateInt(
        transitionSpec = {
            tween(durationMillis = duration.toInt()*text.length)
        },
        label = "caretIndex"
    ) { targetText ->
        Log.d("aos", "targetText: $targetText")
        targetText.length
    }
```

But that also has the previous value and cause crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because your selectedIndex is remembered for the ALayout composable so as long as it's still in composition that value will be persisted regardless of what data is passed into ALayout. If you want selectedIndex to be reset when choiceList changes, then you can pass choiceList as a key of `rememberSaveable` (see example below) which will cause the selectedIndex value to be reset when the choiceList changes.

```
var selectedIndex by rememeberSaveable(choiceList){ mutableStateOf(-1) }
```

For more info on how remember works and what the key does, I think [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#retrigger-remember) is helpful.